# How to scale gridHelper in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';


let scene, camera, renderer, gridHelper;
scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 1500, 0);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);


renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight);

const container = document.getElementById('smallContainer');
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Grid
gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(500, 4, 0xffffff, 0xff0000);
scene.add(gridHelper);
```

> I have a `gridhelper` and i want to change its width and height manually
> , how can i do it? can i scale? this is my code.

```
const v = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1/2, 1);
gridHelper.addScaledVector(v, 1);
```

> I try the code above and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gridHelper.addScaledVector(v, 1);

This code produce a runtime error since `GridHelper` has no method `addScaledVector()`.

Try to modulate the [scale](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.scale) property instead.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  camera.position.set(5, 5, 5);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  const helper = new THREE.GridHelper();
  helper.scale.setScalar(2);
  scene.add(helper);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wanted to change directions in a different way so i combined your code and my code and made this `gridHelper.scale.addScaledVector(v, 1);` and its worked.Thanks for your help